# How to deal with thousands of small audio files?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Need to implement an app that has a feature to play sounds. Each sound will be some word sound, number of expected sounds is about one thousand. So, the most simple solution would be to store those sounds as sound files, each word sound in separate sound file, and to play them on demand. Would there be any potential problems with such a large number of files?

Comment: Have you considered downloading the files from a server after the app is deployed. I know this can have some other issues, but it will give you the flexibility to change the files later. Also just like image striping, not sure if you can load may be one file for 40 sounds and keep a marker as to where it should start and end. That way, file loading time will be minimized. What I found is that as soon as your app is succesful, you will need to port it to other languages etc and having the resources downloaded is some times a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with that many files, but they will take up more space than just the total of their sizes. Each file will fill up a whole # of space blocks on the device. On average you will then waste half a block (as a rule of thumb) unless all your files are significantly smaller than one block, in which case you will always use 1.000 blocks (one pr. file) and waste 1000 * (blocksize - average file size).

Things you could do:

Concatenate the files into one big file, store the start and length of each subfile, either read the chunk into memory or copy to a temporary file.

Drop the files in a database as BLOB fields for easier retrieval. This won't save space, but may make your code simpler or more reliable.

I don't think you need to make your own caching mechanism. Most likely iOS has a system-wide cache that does a far better job. That should only be relevant if you experience performance issues and need to get much shorter load times. In that case prhaps consider using bolcks for loading and dispatching the playing, as that's an easier way to hide the load latency and avoid UI freezes.

If your audio is uncompressed, the App Store will report the compressed size. If that differs a lot from the unpacked size, some (nitpicking) customers will definitely notice ald complain, as they think the advertised size is the install size. I know from personal experience. They wil generally not take a technical answer for an answer, any may even bypass talking to you, and just downvote you based on this. I s#it you not.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine storing 1000 audio clip files within the IPA but it is important to take note about the space requirements and organisation.

Also to take into consideration is the fact that accessing the disk is slower than memory and it also takes up battery space so it my be ideal to load up the most frequently used audio clips into memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford it, use FMOD which I believe can extract audio from various compressed schemes. If you just want to handle all those files yourself create a .zip file and extract them on the fly using libz (iOS library libs.dylib).